# zend framework 2.4 index action

Tags: zend-route

Started on the zend tutorial application. Can't make

```
zf2-tutorial.localhost/album/
```

map to
`zf2-tutorial.localhost/album/index`

But using `zf2-tutorial.localhost/album/index` calls the index action.

Have already set the default action as 'index'

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:
`'route' => '/album[/:action][/:id]'`
To:
`'route' => '/album/[/:action][/:id]',`
in `module.config.php` of album module